# From a lesser known uni, but very prestigious in my country - do I tell my referee to make this clear in my LOR for USA applications?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states, recommendation-letter, united-kingdom

I'm applying to the US and Canada for PhDs this cycle, my undergraduate university is very well regarded in my country (UK) and generally in the top 5 for domestic rankings/prestige. Even more so for my undergrad program (Physics), which generally accepts people who very narrowly missed out on Oxford/Cambridge places. However is pretty much unheard of outside of Britain (ranked in the 60s/70s globally). Do I ask my referees to make the relative prestige of my uni clear on my LOR so that admissions committees can understand the context of my grades and experiences?? Or would this be considered too on the nose?

I am preparing to send materials to all of my referees with some advice on how to write LORs for North American applications, which they may not have done before, so I would really like to clarify this before I do so.

Comment: A top 5 UK university, which is well regarded within your field and top 100 in the world is very unlikely to be unknown to people in the field, even at a university not in the UK. Also, why do you assume your letter writers have never written for an American university before? Unless they are very new to writing letters, that too is quite unlikely.

Comment: I guess to clarify I'm applying for programs outside of my field, in computer science. However my doubt basically stems from discussions with my final year project supervisor, a professor in the department, who expressed inexperience in dealing with non-UK graduate applications.

Comment: _"I am preparing to send of materials to all of my referees with some advice on how to write LORs [...]"._ I would urge you to think long and hard about this idea, and if possible avoid doing it altogether. Your LOR writers will almost surely not appreciate this coming from you, and your estimation of how much they need it is almost certainly way off the mark. Even in the extreme case of a new faculty member who has no LOR writing experience, they surely know their own limitations quite well and know how and where to obtain the necessary advice themselves.

Comment: @DanRomik, thanks for your response. I guess the major concern for me is ensuring that my qualifications or references are not dismissed by admissions tutors at top programs if they don't recognise my university. I will bear this in mind when applying.

Comment: The UK has some of the most highly respected universities in the world, yet you write as if it's some kind of third-world backwater.

Comment: @David: I heartily agree with your first clause; with regard to the second, I think the OP's mistake is not to realize the extent to which academics spend a lifetime acquiring information about academia.  I am at a university that no one would ever claim is in the top 100 in the world, but nevertheless my department (mathematics) is known and respected by many European mathematicians.

Comment: @DanRomik, disagree completely. Even esteemed scholars need guidance on how to write letters, and most of them appreciate this: it just makes their work simpler. Of course there may be some exceptions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First of all, it is a tough position to be in as a student to have to give faculty advice on how to write your graduate school letter of recommendation.  To give them too much guidance may not be appropriate, and as someone who has not yet completed a PhD program or read or written any such letters, you almost certainly don't have the expertise do properly advise them either.  Thus I would urge you rather to seek out writers who have previous experience writing letters to North American universities.  One of the most important qualities of a top world university is that they regularly place their students at other top world universities, so (as @Tobias Kildetoft has pointed out in comment) I would expect there to be many faculty members in your department who have experience writing such letters.  I think it is much less awkward to try to choose letter writers based on this expertise than to try to give your letter writers letter writing advice.

But assuming the premise of the proposal: it is not clear to me exactly what information you are hoping to provide.  The world's top hundred universities are largely well known to each other, and moreover it is the responsibility of those who are evaluating your application to know or learn enough about your university in order to perform that evaluation.  When I do graduate admissions and get an application from an institution that I am not familiar with, I do spend time familiarizing myself with it.

In terms of rankings: Times Higher Education [a London based magazine] [places twelve UK universities within the world's top hundred](https://www.timeshighereducation.com/world-university-rankings/2018/world-ranking#!/page/0/length/25/sort_by/rank/sort_order/asc/cols/stats): Oxford (1), Cambridge (4), Imperial (8), University College London (15), London School of Economics (25), Edinburgh (27), King's College (36), Manchester (55), Bristol (71), Warwick (82), Glasgow (88), Durham (96).  It is reasonable to expect a reputable North American PhD program to have heard of all of these institutions.    Individual faculty members will also have their own opinions on the relative merits: for instance, in terms of the kind of mathematics that I do, I view Bristol as being very strong, perhaps at about the same level as Imperial.

If the faculty who process graduate admission do not agree that your institution is one of the world's most prestigious, simply pointing out that it is one of the top ones in the UK according to some metric may not change their mind.  They should instead offer concrete evidence of the excellence of their program, e.g. by talking about world-leading faculty members and former students who have been placed in other top institutions.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will bear this advice in mind. This question probably stems from my naivety, however my main concern was ensuring that my qualifications were recognised as an international applicant and was worried that my application would be dismissed by top programs as if they didn't know the context of my experiences.

Comment: If you look specifically at Physics rankings, this https://www.thecompleteuniversityguide.co.uk/league-tables/rankings?s=physics%20%26%20astronomy has a somewhat different top 5. No surprise that Oxford Cambridge and Imperial College London are in there, but the other two are St Andrews (in Scotland) and Durham. I don't know whether to believe these scores but I could certainly believe that St Andrews was not particularly well known (except for its golf courses!) outside the UK.

Comment: @alephzero: I was a bit surprised not to see St Andrews in the THE top 100.  It does appear highly in some other lists.  And for what it's worth, I think of it as an excellent institution.  Still, if I read a letter saying "Actually St Andrews is considered by some reputable sources to be in the top five of UK physics programs," as an admissions faculty member I don't know quite what to do with that -- I need help translating that into the sort of tiers I usually think about.  (Also: great undergraduate program in X in a less great university is easier to sell to most nations than to the US.)